# How to solve $y''(x) - \frac{2}{x^2} y(x) = 0$ by separation of variables?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> How to solve $y''(x) - \frac{2}{x^2} y(x) = 0$ by separation of
>   variables ?

First of all, is it possible ? Secondly, if so, how ?

Note that, this ODE can be solved by other methods also, or you can even guess the solutions, (for example $x^2$ and $x^{-1}$ satisfies ODE), but I'm particularly interested in how it can be solve by the method of separation of variables.

Comment: What happens with $\dfrac{y''}{y} = \dfrac{2}{x^2}$?

Comment: @Henry After $\frac{d^2 y}{y} = \frac{2 (dx)^2}{x}$, how can we proceed ? That is the exact point that I have stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $y=x^2u$ and substitute:
$$y^{'}=2xu+x^2u^{'}\to y^{"}=2u+4xu^{'}+x^2u^{"}$$

therefore we have:

$$4xu^{'}+x^2u^{"}=0\to 4u^{'}+xu^{"}=0\to {{u^{"}}\over{u^{'}}}=-{4\over x}\to lnu^{'}=-4lnx+C_1\to u^{'}={{C_1}\over {x^4}}\to u={{C_1}\over {x^3}}+C_2$$

and the final answer is

$$y={{C_1}\over {x}}+{{C_2}{x^2}}$$

Comment: from your solution $y''=\frac{30C_1}{x^7}+\frac{6C_2}{x^4}$. so $0=\frac{30C_1}{x^7}+\frac{6C_2}{x^4}-\frac2{x^2}({{C_1}\over {x^5}}+{{C_2}\over {x^2}})=\frac{30C_1}{x^7}+\frac{6C_2}{x^4}-{{2C_1}\over {x^7}}-{{2C_2}\over {x^4}}=\frac{28C_1}{x^7}+\frac{4C_2}{x^4}\ne0$

Comment: how did you conclude $u'' / u' = ln(u')$ ? Can you explicitly show your work because that is one of the points where I'm having difficulty to understand.

Comment: The solution for $u$ is right. You just made a mistake when computing $y$. It should be $y = x^2 u$, not $u/x^2$

Comment: @onurcanbektas $(\ln u')' = u''/u' $

Comment: and in the last integral you forgot $-$, it should be $-\frac{C_1}{x^3}$ or $\frac{C_3}{x^3}$

Comment: @Holo That's not important as the negative would be absorbed into the constant anyway

Comment: Constants are not of high importance since you can replace $C$ with f(C) most oftenly.

Comment: That's right! Thank you I recorrected it!!

Comment: @Dylan From that perspective, it is clear, but from starting here: $\frac{d^2 u * dx}{(dx)^2 * d u } = \frac{-4}{x} \Rightarrow \frac{d^2 u}{du} = \frac{-4 dx}{x}$ how can we end up there.

Comment: @onurcanbektas Think of it as $$ \frac{d(u')}{u'} = -4\frac{dx}{x} $$ Since $u'' = \frac{d(u')}{dx}$

Comment: @Dylan How ? Can you put a $dx$ inside $d( ... )$ ?

Comment: Do note that separation of variables only work for *first-order* equations. As such, you have to treat this as a first-order equation in $u'$. It helps to do another change of variable $z = u'$. This is why the original $y$ equation isn't seperable

Comment: @Dylan see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2599406/how-to-solve-yx-frac2x2-yx-0-by-separation-of-variables#comment5367313_2599425

Comment: Sure! what's the derivation of $ln(u^{'})$?

Answer (score 3):

Separation of variables is a technique for **first-order** ODE. It will not work for second order ODE. Most ODE of the form $y''+f(x)y=0$ are not solvable symbolically (apart from giving fancy names to solutions of normal forms of these equations). For the most famous example look under *[Airy equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function)*.

---

However,
$$
x^2y''-2y=0
$$
is an Euler-Cauchy ODE. As such you can find basis solution using the form $y=x^m$ which inserted leads to
$$
m(m-1)-2=0\iff (m+1)(m-2)=0
$$
so that all solutions are of the form
$$
y=C_1x^{-1}+C_2x^2.
$$

Comment: Why does the method of separation of variables only works for first-order ODE ? Is there any counterexample that shows that this method generates wrong solutions if the ODE is not first order ?

Comment: Your confusion comes from treating the derivative operator as a fraction. This is in fact only a shorthand that works with a single derivative. As you have shown, you cannot integrate something with a $(dx)^2$.

Comment: It's not that it generates wrong solutions, it's that the method literally cannot be applied.

Comment: @Dylan I see, but I just want to ask something, I often see something like $\int f(r) d^3 r$ for volume integrals. Is this just a wrong usage of the notation or something entirely different ?

Comment: No, that is a shorthand for a volume integral, that is, $d^3\vec r=d^3\mathbf r=d^3\mathfrak x=dx\,dy\,dz$.

Comment: It may possible to interpret $\int f(x) (dx)^2$ as a multiple integral $\int\left(\int f(x) dx\right) dx$. However, that's a different context entirely, and the $d^2y$ on the other side would still be nonsensical

Comment: @Dylan and LutzL, thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 2):

Because there are $2$ answers that show $2$ different ways i will post another very commonly used way

---

rewrite the equation: $x^2y''-2y=0$

set $t=\ln(x),\phi(t)=\phi(\ln(x))=y(x)$

from there we get $$\dfrac{d\phi}{dx}=\frac1x\frac{d\phi}{dt}\\\dfrac{d^2\phi}{dx^2}=\frac1{x^2}\left(\frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2}-\frac{d\phi}{dt}\right)$$

let's return to the original equation and put $\phi,\phi''$ instead of $y,y''$:$$x^2y''-2y=x^2\frac1{x^2}\left(\phi''-\phi'\right)-2\phi=\phi''-\phi'-2\phi=0$$this is a simple second-order ODE, we solve this and get $\phi(t)=c_1e^{-t}+c_2e^{2t}$ we remember that $t=\ln(x)$ to get $$\boxed{y(x)=c_1x^{-1}+c_2x^2}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is a good method.

Comment: this method will always work for Euler-Cauchy ODE, i.e. equation in the form of $a_{n}x^{n}y^{(n)}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}y^{(n-1)}+\cdots+a_{2}x^{2}y''+a_{1}xy'+a_0y=0$($y^{(k)}=k$-th derivative of y). from this you can see why trying basis solution of $y=x^m$ works