# Differential equation:$y''-(y')^2=-\frac{2}{(x+a)^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, contest-math

Find the general solution to this differential equation:
$$y''-(y')^2=-\frac{2}{(x+a)^2}.$$
The result is that:$$\ln (a+x)-\ln (x^3+3ax^2+3a^2x+c_1)+c_2,$$where $c_1,c_2$ are arbitrary constants.$$\\$$
This differential equation comes from a contest exercise:

> $f(x)$ is second differentiable in $[a,b],f(a)=f'(a)=f''(a)=f(b)=0.$
> Prove:$$\exists \ \xi\in(a,b),s.t.(\xi-a)^2f''(\xi)-2f(\xi)=0.$$

The auxiliary function is determined by undetermined function method.

Comment: The result is that:$\ln (a+x)-\ln (x^3+3ax^2+3a^2x+c_1)+c_2$,where $c_1,c_2$ are arbitrary constants.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Bonnaduck I have just learned the knowledge of linear differential equations, and I have no idea about nonlinear problems. This is a problem I got by transforming another problem.

Comment: Hint: Let $u=y'$. Then $u'-u^2=-2/(x+1)^2$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I get it.But there is no essential difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity WLOG let just consider that $y$ is a function of $(x+a)$, we can translate the resulting function in the end.

$$y''-(y')^2=-\frac 2{x^2}$$

Notice that $\left(\dfrac{u'}{u}\right)'=\dfrac{u''}u-\left(\dfrac{u'}u\right)^2$

So you see that when setting $y'=-\frac{u'}u$ the term in $(y')^2$ will just cancel in the ODE.

Therefore let set $y=-\ln(u)$ and we get

$$\frac{u''}{u}=\frac 2{x^2}$$

Then look at [How to solve $y''(x) - \frac{2}{x^2} y(x) = 0$ by separation of variables?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2599406/399263)

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=y'$ and set $f(x)=-2/(x+a)^2$. Then we have

$$u'=u^2+f(x)$$

Let $v(x)=\frac{u(x)}{f(x)^{1/2}}$. Then

\begin{align*}
u(x)&=v(x)\cdot f(x)^{1/2}\\
u'(x)&=v'(x)\cdot f(x)^{1/2}+v(x)\cdot \frac{f'(x)}{2f(x)^{1/2}},
\end{align*}

transforming our equation to

\begin{align*}
\frac{dv}{dx}f(x)^{1/2}+v\frac{f'(x)}{2f(x)^{1/2}}=v^2f(x)+f(x)&\implies dvf(x)^{1/2}+v\frac{f'(x)}{2f(x)^{1/2}}dx=v^2f(x)dx+f(x)dx\\
&\implies \frac1vdv=(v+\frac1v)f(x)^{1/2}dx-\frac{f'(x)}{2f(x)}dx\\
&\implies \frac1vdv=(v+\frac1v)\frac{\sqrt{-2}}{x+a}dx+\frac{1}{x+a}dx\\
&\implies \frac1vdv=\left[(v+\frac1v)\sqrt{-2}+1\right]\frac1{x+a}dx\\
&\implies\frac{1}{i\sqrt{2}v^2+v+i\sqrt{2}}dv=\frac1{x+a}dx\\
&\implies \frac13\ln(\sqrt2-2iv)-\frac13\ln(\sqrt2+iv) = \ln(x+a)+c_1'\\
&\implies \frac{\sqrt2-2iv}{\sqrt2+iv} = (x+a)^3c_1\\
\end{align*}

We now substitute back

\begin{align*}
\frac{\sqrt2-2iv}{\sqrt2+iv} = (x+a)^3c_1&\implies \frac{\sqrt2-2i\frac u{f^{1/2}}}{\sqrt2+i\frac u{f^{1/2}}} = (x+a)^3c_1\\
&\implies \frac{\sqrt2f^{1/2}-2iu}{\sqrt2f^{1/2}+iu} = (x+a)^3c_1\\
&\implies \frac{\frac{2i}{x+a}-2iu}{\frac{2i}{x+a}+iu} = (x+a)^3c_1\\
&\implies \frac{2-2u(x+a)}{2+u(x+a)} = (x+a)^3c_1\\
&\implies u=\frac{2-2(x+a)^3c_1}{2(x+a)+(x+a)^4c_1}\\
\end{align*}

Finally, substituting back to $y'$ gives us

\begin{align*}
y=\int\frac{2-2(x+a)^3c_1}{2(x+a)+(x+a)^4c_1}dx&=\ln(x+a)-\ln(c_1(x+a)^3+2)+c_2\\
&=\ln(x+a)-\ln(x^3+x^2a+xa^2+d_1)+d_2
\end{align*}